# Invoke Lambda Function with SNS with arguments defined at subscription time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I’ll describe what I’m trying to do then my current solution.

I currently have an ECS Fargate Cluster with a number of services that cache some configuration information. What I want is when the configuration changes, a message is sent on SNS, and all tasks reload their configuration.

My first approach was, when the task starts to subscribe via HTTP to SNS. This has the problem that if the task dies or doesn’t shutdown cleanly you end up with a bunch of orphan subscriptions. My next idea was to have a lambda function that is called, that can call the tasks’s http endpoint, and if the endpoint is down, it will unsubscribe itself.

What I need to do now is when I subscribe a lambda is to be able to somehow pass some arguments that should be sent when the subscription is invoked. Currently I’ve managed to hack it by publishing a new version with new environment variables but this process is racy if two tasks try to subscribe simultaneously. Is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 2):

Let me summarize your problem with different words to check if I understood it correctly:

- you have multiple running tasks
- sometimes one of these tasks has its state changed (config info cache)
- when it happens, you want all other tasks to be informed.

If my understanding is correct, I would not consider SNS subscriptions to solve the problem.

I would not do it because I consider an SNS subscription a more stable component,
like being part of your architecture.
Not something that comes and goes when a task is initialized or finished.

Instead, I would work with CloudTrail/EventBridge/DynamoDB/Lambda.
Here is a suggestion:

- Create an EventBridge rule that captures all events associated with a task initialization/termination
- Forward these events to a Lambda Function that will add/remove a record to/from a DynamoDB table with the active tasks.
- Inside the tasks, publishes a new Event to EventBridge when the state changes (config info cached).
- Create an EventBridge rule that captures these events and sends them to another Lambda Function.
- In the second Lambda Function read all active tasks from DynamoDB and made the appropriate request to the tasks.

Comment: This is a good solution, but it involves more AWS services than I'd like.